# Power Apps: Patch function: Update field with click of Icon

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms

Trying to update my save icon to update my field "Status" to "In Progress".

Does anyone know how I can update my formula to do this?
My status field is based off a sharepoint "choices" column.

```
Patch(
    [@'Questionnaire'],
    ThisItem,
    {'Status':  {Value: "In Progress"}
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you miss a closing bracket "}" after giving the value of the choice field. So the correct formula would be:

```
Patch(
    [@'Questionnaire'],
    ThisItem,
    {'Status':  {Value: "In Progress"}}
)
```

Bet you gonna "doh" on this one :D